# Why my @State doesn't change my conditional statement?

Tags: swift, if-statement, swiftui

I have a conditional statement to show a @State to the user either to sign in or sign up. When I click on the SignIn$SignUpButton, the @State of the button change but my conditional statement doesn't trigger.

Is there anything missing?

```
struct CredentialsView: View {

  @State var signInSelected = true
  @State var signUpSelected = false

  @State var firstName = ""
  @State var email = ""
  @State var password = ""
  @State var confirmPassword = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      SignIn$SingUpButton(signInSelected: signInSelected,
                          signUpSelected: signUpSelected
      )

      VStack(spacing: 30) {
        if signInSelected {
          UserEntryTextField(title: "email", userEntry: email)
          UserEntryTextField(title: "password", userEntry: password)
        }
        else if signUpSelected {
          UserEntryTextField(title: "first name", userEntry: firstName)
          UserEntryTextField(title: "email", userEntry: email)
          UserEntryTextField(title: "password", userEntry: password)
          UserEntryTextField(title: "confirm Password", userEntry: confirmPassword)
        }
      }
      .padding(.top, signInSelected ? 110 : 50)
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding(.vertical, 40)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use @Binding in order to achieve that. Look at the examples about binding you will understand more clearly

Answer (score 0):

I had to change some things to make it run but the principle should be clear, is this what are you intended to do?

```
struct CredentialsView: View {

  @State var signInSelected = true

  @State var firstName = ""
  @State var email = ""
  @State var password = ""
  @State var confirmPassword = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("hola"){
                self.signInSelected.toggle()
            }

            VStack() {
                if signInSelected {
                    Text( "password")
                }
                else {
                   Text( "confirm Password")
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, signInSelected ? 110 : 50)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 40)
    }
}
```

Comment: What was necessary is to add Binding in my SingIn$SignUpButton struct to keep track of my changing State of my signInSelected variable as Bartu Akman suggest in his answer.